# Работает ли javascript AJAX в wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress, json

Здравствуйте, разбираюсь с движком вордпрес и столкнулся с трудность при работе с ajax, причем через jquery получилось отправить запрос и получить ответ от сервера, а на чистом js нет, но я хочу разобраться т.к. не по кайфе ради одного аякса грузить библиотеку JQ. 
В общем рабочий код на JQ:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.submit_form').on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            action: 'flat_app'
        };
        $.post(window.wp.admin_path, data, function(){

        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

Статус 200 ОК, ответ получен.
Дальше решил то же написать на js, получилось следующее:

```
var subm = document.querySelector('.submit_form');
var fm = document.forms.test_form;
var obj = { action: 'flat_app' };
// var obj_json = JSON.stringify(obj);
subm.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var q = new XMLHttpRequest();
    q.open("POST", window.wp.admin_path, true);
    q.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-urlencoded");
    q.send(obj);

    q.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(q.readyState == 4 && q.status == 200){
            console.log(q.responseText);
        }
    };

});
```

Статус 400 вордпрес отвергает запрос, ответ 0. 
Тут я пробовал отправлять как объект так и JSON строку, но ответ все тот же 400.

Код который принимает на сервере:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'ajax_data');

function ajax_data () {
    $phpVars = [
        'admin_path' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    ];
    echo "<script> window.wp = " . json_encode($phpVars) . "</script>";
}

add_action('wp_ajax_flat_app', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_flat_app', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback () {
    echo "privet";

    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: obj нужно сериализовать в `action=flat_app` или с json передавать корректный content-type (хотя не уверен, что wp из коробки будет его десериализовывать)

Comment: json и www-urlencoded - разные форматы

Comment: да я это делал там строчка закомментированная есть // var obj_json = JSON.stringify(obj);

Comment: Ещё раз: `action=flat_app` немножко отличается от `{"action": "flat_app"}`

Comment: Поменял q.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); ответ 400 все равно

Comment: Значит я был прав в `не уверен, что wp из коробки будет его десериализовывать`. `q.send('action=flat_app')` работает?

Comment: Реализация сериализации в jQuery [$.param](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js#L59-L92)

Comment: Спс бро)) заработало)) как тебе плюсик поставить тут? )

Comment: Никак, кто-нибудь нормальный ответ напишет, ему и поставишь =)

Comment: Ладно спасибо за помощь, реально помог и все работает :)

Comment: 400 был потому, что admin-ajax.php не получал $_POST['action']. В этом случае он отвечает 400.

Comment: Слушай дружище, раз уж такая пьянка пошла то задам еще один вопрос. :) Как такое может быть, когда я получаю данные с глобального массива $_POST[""] и echo вывожу то js не получает строки но получает числа) Как такое может быть? ))Это наверное что-то в вордпресе?

Comment: код - http://joxi.ru/gmvXNPCx5q3NAa если отправляю числа то - http://joxi.ru/Vm6Y1JCxy4PPrZ ну а если отправляю строки то - http://joxi.ru/8AnlnPTqbzeDmO

Comment: Я случайно увидел комментарий. Если пишете кому-то, ставьте @ перед именем. А по сути - лучше задать новый вопрос

Answer (score 0):

jQuery это лишь обертка над Javascript, поэтому если работает на jQuery, то будет работать и на чистом JS